# Plotting eigenbehaviours with matplotlib

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot eigenbehaviors with matplotlib, basically I have a 2D matrix and would like to plot it with something very similar to a heat map, but the cells are divided and recognizable. See for example:

http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~nv240/pics/eigenbehaviour.jpg

Comment: apparently they got it without it ;)

Comment: Yes ;) +1 to you and to them!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

[image]

```
from pylab import *

z = rand(10, 25)

c = pcolor(z)
set_cmap('hot')
colorbar()
c = pcolor(z, edgecolors='w', linewidths=1)
axis([0,25,0,10])
savefig('plt.png')
show()
```

Comment: On a side note, `pcolormesh` is a better choice (performance-wise) for a regular grid. `pcolor` is slower, but will handle arbitrary meshes.

Comment: thanks, that's exactly what i'm after. this should actually be one of the examples in matplotlib's docs.

Comment: The link provided by the OP is forbidden.