# Matplotlib grayscale heatmap with visually distinct "NA" squares fields

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I am creating a heatmap to be used in a publication.  The publication is restricted to black and white printing, so I'm creating the heatmap in grayscale.  The problem I have is that there are some squares in the heatmap which are "Not Applicable" which I want to visually differentiate from the other cells.  My understanding is that this may(?) be possible using numpy's masked arrays if the heatmap is colored at both ends of the scale, and that masked fields may simply display as white.  The problem is, I would like to use the full spectrum from white to black to illustrate the range of the non-NA data.  Is there anyway to distinguish NA cells with some other visual mechanism, such as a strikethrough?

Below is a minimum example of grayscale with a masked array (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10757751/129475)).  The NA values are probably masked here, you just can't tell because it is using white which is already being used as the color on the high end of the valid spectrum.

```
import numpy as np
from pylab import *

z = rand(10, 25)
z = np.ma.masked_array(z,mask=z>0.8)

c = pcolor(z)
set_cmap('gray')
colorbar()
c = pcolor(z, edgecolors='w', linewidths=1)
axis([0,25,0,10])
savefig('plt.png')
show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A simple solution is to just hatch the background axes patch.  E.g.:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
np.random.seed(1977)

data = np.random.random((10,25))
data = np.ma.masked_greater(data, 0.8)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.pcolormesh(data, cmap=cm.gray, edgecolors='white', linewidths=1,
                   antialiased=True)
fig.colorbar(im)

ax.patch.set(hatch='xx', edgecolor='black')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that if you'd prefer not to have the borders drawn in between empty cells, you can use `pcolor` instead of `pcolormesh`. For example, if we change the line:

```
im = ax.pcolormesh(data, cmap=cm.gray, edgecolors='white', linewidths=1,
                   antialiased=True)
```

to:

```
im = ax.pcolor(data, cmap=cm.gray, edgecolors='white', linewidths=1)
```

We'll get:

[image]

The difference is subtle -- Lines are not drawn between adjacent empty cells with `pcolor`.  Which aesthetics you prefer is purely personal, but it highlights a key difference between `pcolor` and `pcolormesh`.

Comment: Hi Joe! Using matplotlib version 1.4.3, I had to add `ax.patch.set_edgecolor('black')` to make the hatch marks visible. I'm not sure if that is needed in general or if it is just because my version is old.

Comment: @unutbu - Thanks! It also needs to be set in 1.5, as well. I was implicitly relying on the patch's edgecolor being set, which is never a good thing.  Better to explicitly set it, regardless of differences between versions.

Comment: hello @JoeKington, thanks for your answer. What if I want to plot the same thing but for a huge matrix (100k lines, 200 columns) in order to have a general idea about where are the nans concentrated?

Comment: @msalem - In that case, use `imshow` instead of `pcolor` or `pcolormesh`. You can either use the hatching trick, or the `set_bad` method of the colormap to set the NaNs to whatever color/style you'd like. Imshow is much faster that the other options for large arrays, though.

Answer (score 3):

I was not able to reproduce Joe's answer by adding a patch by `ax.patch.set_hatch('x')`. Instead I had to create the patch as a rectangle according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18403408/2573523) as

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.patches as patches

data = np.random.random((10,25))
data = np.ma.masked_greater(data, 0.8)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.pcolormesh(data, cmap=cm.gray, edgecolors='white', linewidths=0)
fig.colorbar(im)

# ax.patch.set_hatch('x')  replaced by:
p = patches.Rectangle((0,0), 25, 10, hatch='xx', fill=None,zorder=-10)
ax.add_patch(p)

plt.show()
```

Furthermore, `pcolormesh` seems to be sorted out by now, so one can use it here.