# Python: Leave Numpy NaN values from matplotlib heatmap and its legend

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, heatmap, nan

I have a numpy array that I need to plot as a heatmap. The numpy array would also contain NaN values which I need to exclude from plotting. I was told in other posts that numpy automatically masks the NaN values in the plot, but its somehow not working for me. Here is a sample code

```
column_labels = list('ABCDEFGH')
row_labels = list('WXYZ')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data = np.array([[ 0.96753494,  0.52349944,  0.0254628 ,  0.5104103 ],
         [ 0.07320069,  0.91278731,  0.97094436,  0.70533351],
         [ 0.30162006,  0.49068337,  0.41837729,  0.71139215],
         [ 0.19786101,  0.15882713,  0.59028841,  0.06242765],
         [ 0.51505872,  0.07798389,  0.58790067,  0.44782683],
         [ 0.68975694,  0.53535385,  0.15696023,  0.35641951],
         [ 0.66481995,  0.03576846,  0.9623601 ,  0.96006395],
         [ 0.45865404,  0.50433582,  0.18182575,  0.35126449],])

data[3,:] = np.nan
heatmap = ax.pcolor(data, cmap=plt.cm.seismic)

fig.colorbar(heatmap)
# put the major ticks at the middle of each cell
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data.shape[1])+0.5, minor=False)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data.shape[0])+0.5, minor=False)

# want a more natural, table-like display
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.xaxis.tick_top()

ax.set_xticklabels(row_labels, minor=False)
ax.set_yticklabels(column_labels, minor=False)
plt.show()
```

The plots looks like[image]

Clearly this is very different from the plot without the Nan which looks like [image]

I want to avoid the NaN values completely from the legend and preferably mark it with some symbol such as **X**. How can I achieve the same?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `nans` interfere with `pcolor` determining the range of values contained in `data` since

```
In [72]: data.min(), data.max()
Out[72]: (nan, nan)
```

You can work around the problem by declaring the range of values yourself using `np.nanmin` and `np.nanmax` to find the minimum and maximum non-NaN values in `data`:

```
heatmap = ax.pcolor(data, cmap=plt.cm.seismic, 
                    vmin=np.nanmin(data), vmax=np.nanmax(data))
```

since

```
In [73]: np.nanmin(data), np.nanmax(data)
Out[73]: (0.025462800000000001, 0.97094435999999995)
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

column_labels = list('ABCDEFGH')
row_labels = list('WXYZ')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data = np.array([[ 0.96753494,  0.52349944,  0.0254628 ,  0.5104103 ],
         [ 0.07320069,  0.91278731,  0.97094436,  0.70533351],
         [ 0.30162006,  0.49068337,  0.41837729,  0.71139215],
         [ 0.19786101,  0.15882713,  0.59028841,  0.06242765],
         [ 0.51505872,  0.07798389,  0.58790067,  0.44782683],
         [ 0.68975694,  0.53535385,  0.15696023,  0.35641951],
         [ 0.66481995,  0.03576846,  0.9623601 ,  0.96006395],
         [ 0.45865404,  0.50433582,  0.18182575,  0.35126449],])

data[3,:] = np.nan
heatmap = ax.pcolor(data, cmap=plt.cm.seismic, 
                    vmin=np.nanmin(data), vmax=np.nanmax(data))
heatmap.cmap.set_under('black')

bar = fig.colorbar(heatmap, extend='both')

# put the major ticks at the middle of each cell
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data.shape[1])+0.5, minor=False)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data.shape[0])+0.5, minor=False)

# want a more natural, table-like display
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.xaxis.tick_top()

ax.set_xticklabels(row_labels, minor=False)
ax.set_yticklabels(column_labels, minor=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Another option (based on [Joe Kington's
solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16125413/190597)) would be to draw
rectangular patches with hatch marks wherever `data` is NaN.

The above example shows that `pcolor` colors in cells with NaN values as
though the NaNs were very negative numbers. In contrast, if you pass `pcolor` a
*masked array*, `pcolor` leaves the masked areas transparent. Thus, you can draw
hatches on the axes background patch, `ax.patch`, to show hatch marks
on the masked areas.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

column_labels = list('ABCDEFGH')
row_labels = list('WXYZ')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data = np.array([[ 0.96753494,  0.52349944,  0.0254628 ,  0.5104103 ],
         [ 0.07320069,  0.91278731,  0.97094436,  0.70533351],
         [ 0.30162006,  0.49068337,  0.41837729,  0.71139215],
         [ 0.19786101,  0.15882713,  0.59028841,  0.06242765],
         [ 0.51505872,  0.07798389,  0.58790067,  0.44782683],
         [ 0.68975694,  0.53535385,  0.15696023,  0.35641951],
         [ 0.66481995,  0.03576846,  0.9623601 ,  0.96006395],
         [ 0.45865404,  0.50433582,  0.18182575,  0.35126449],])

data[3,:] = np.nan
data = np.ma.masked_invalid(data)

heatmap = ax.pcolor(data, cmap=plt.cm.seismic, 
                    vmin=np.nanmin(data), vmax=np.nanmax(data))
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/16125413/190597 (Joe Kington)
ax.patch.set(hatch='x', edgecolor='black')
fig.colorbar(heatmap)

# put the major ticks at the middle of each cell
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data.shape[1])+0.5, minor=False)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data.shape[0])+0.5, minor=False)

# want a more natural, table-like display
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.xaxis.tick_top()

ax.set_xticklabels(row_labels, minor=False)
ax.set_yticklabels(column_labels, minor=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

If you have wish to use more than one type of hatch mark, say one for NaNs and another for negative values, then you could use a loop to add the hatched Rectangles:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

column_labels = list('ABCDEFGH')
row_labels = list('WXYZ')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data = np.array([[ 0.96753494,  0.52349944,  0.0254628 ,  0.5104103 ],
         [ 0.07320069,  0.91278731,  0.97094436,  0.70533351],
         [ 0.30162006,  0.49068337,  0.41837729,  0.71139215],
         [ 0.19786101,  0.15882713,  0.59028841,  0.06242765],
         [ 0.51505872,  0.07798389,  0.58790067,  0.44782683],
         [ 0.68975694,  0.53535385,  0.15696023,  0.35641951],
         [ 0.66481995,  0.03576846,  0.9623601 ,  0.96006395],
         [ 0.45865404,  0.50433582,  0.18182575,  0.35126449],])
data -= 0.5
data[3,:] = np.nan
data = np.ma.masked_invalid(data)
heatmap = ax.pcolor(data, cmap=plt.cm.seismic, 
                    vmin=np.nanmin(data), vmax=np.nanmax(data))

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/16125413/190597 (Joe Kington)
ax.patch.set(hatch='x', edgecolor='black')

# draw a hatched rectangle wherever the data is negative
# http://matthiaseisen.com/pp/patterns/p0203/
mask = data < 0
for j, i in np.column_stack(np.where(mask)):
      ax.add_patch(
          mpatches.Rectangle(
              (i, j),     # (x,y)
              1,          # width
              1,          # height
              fill=False, 
              edgecolor='blue',
              snap=False,
              hatch='x' # the more slashes, the denser the hash lines 
          ))

fig.colorbar(heatmap)

# put the major ticks at the middle of each cell
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data.shape[1])+0.5, minor=False)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data.shape[0])+0.5, minor=False)

# want a more natural, table-like display
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.xaxis.tick_top()

ax.set_xticklabels(row_labels, minor=False)
ax.set_yticklabels(column_labels, minor=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to add a symbol like x or something to the nan values

Comment: I added `heatmap.cmap.set_under('black')` to color the NaNs black -- a color not in the seismic colormap. Would that do?

Comment: Is it possible to add multiple patches, say one for NaN and one for negative values, or is it best to achieve it by applying the masked array twice

Comment: I think the overlay trick can only be used with one hatch. If you need two kinds of hatches, you could add the second using a loop. I've added an example above to show what I mean.